Github action login to execute push
I want to check if any directory inside charts-v2/core/ or charts-v2/platform/
is changed and then if changed execute helm cm push
Somehow below code is not working
name: Push Changed Charts

on:
  push:
    branches: ["helm-autopush-charts-base"]

jobs:
  push-changed-charts:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: helm-autopush-charts-base

     
      - name: Get changed charts
        id: get-changed-charts
        run: |
          CHANGED_CHARTS=$(git show --format="" --name-only | xargs dirname | grep -E 'charts-v2/(core|platform)' | awk -F'/' '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3}' | sort | uniq)
          CHANGED_CHARTS=$(echo "$CHANGED_CHARTS" | tr '\n' ' ')
          echo "::set-output name=changed_charts::$CHANGED_CHARTS"
        
      - name: Push changed charts
        run: |
          IFS=$'\n' read -r -a CHART_ARRAY <<< "${{ steps.list-changed.outputs.changed_charts_core }}"
          for chart in "${CHART_ARRAY[@]}"; do
            chart_name=$(basename "$chart")
            helm cm-push "./$chart" "${{ secrets.CHARTMUSEUM_URL }}/" -f
          done

can someone help

How it's not working. Please give more info.

it is not giving the directory in which charts have been changed

so once the code is merged to helm-autopush-charts-base base branch then it is unable to tell us which charts inside have been changed inside charts-v2/core or charts-v2/platform so CHANGED_CHARTS is always null

Try to change from:
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a CHART_ARRAY <<< "${{ steps.list-changed.outputs.changed_charts_core }}"

To:
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a CHART_ARRAY <<< "${{ steps.get-changed-charts.outputs.changed_charts }}"

